# Why If elif statement run twice?

Tags: python

This is my code, very simple, just use regex to find in a String and change the list element:

```
header=['premium','ri pre','ri prepaid']
import re

for i in range(len(header)):
    j=0
    print(i)
    print(header[i])
    if re.search('.*policy.*no.*',header[i],flags=re.IGNORECASE) is not None:
        header[i]='POLICY NO'
        print(1)
        print(header[i])
        j=j+1
    elif re.search('.*endor.*',header[i],flags=re.IGNORECASE) is not None:
        header[i]='ENDORSEMENT NO'
        print(2)
        print(header[i])
        j=j+1
    elif  re.search('.*customer.*',header[i],flags=re.IGNORECASE) is not None:
        header[i]='CUSTOMER NAME'
        print(3)
        print(header[i])
        j=j+1
    elif  re.search('.*inception.*',header[i],flags=re.IGNORECASE) is not None:
        header[i]='INCEPTION DATE'
        print(4)
        print(header[i])
        j=j+1
    elif  re.search('.*maturity.*',header[i],flags=re.IGNORECASE) is not None:
        header[i]='MATURITY DATE'
        print(5)
        print(header[i])
        j=j+1
    elif  re.search('.*currency.*',header[i],flags=re.IGNORECASE) is not None:
        header[i]='CURRENCY CODE'
        print(6)
        print(header[i])
        j=j+1
    elif  re.search('.*sum.*insured.*',header[i],flags=re.IGNORECASE) is not None:
        header[i]='SUM INSURED'
        print(7)
        print(header[i])
        j=j+1
    elif  re.search('.*ri.*net.*pre.*',header[i],flags=re.IGNORECASE) is not None:
        header[i]='RI NET PREMIUM'
        print(8)
        print(header[i])
        j=j+1
    elif  re.search('.*net.*pre.*',header[i],flags=re.IGNORECASE) is not None:
        header[i]='NET PREMIUM'
        print(9)
        print(header[i])
        j=j+1
    elif  re.search('.*ri.*share.*',header[i],flags=re.IGNORECASE) is not None:
        header[i]='RI SHARE'
        print(10) 
        print(header[i])
        j=j+1
    elif  re.search('.*ri.*pre.*paid.*',header[i],flags=re.IGNORECASE) is not None:
        header[i]='RI PREPAID'
        print(11)  
        print(header[i])
        j=j+1
    elif  re.search('.*ri.*pre.*',header[i],flags=re.IGNORECASE) is not None:
        header[i]='RI PREMIUM'
        print(12)
        print(header[i])
        j=j+1
    if re.search('.*balance.*',header[i],flags=re.IGNORECASE) is not None:
        header[i]='BALANCE'  
        print(13)
        print(header[i])
        j=j+1
    elif  re.search('.*ri.*com.*',header[i],flags=re.IGNORECASE) is not None:
        header[i]='RI COMM'
        print(14)
        print(header[i])
        j=j+1
    elif  re.search('.*ri.*tax.*',header[i],flags=re.IGNORECASE) is not None:
        header[i]='RI TAX'
        print(15)
        print(header[i])
        j=j+1
    elif  re.search('.*uw.*year.*',header[i],flags=re.IGNORECASE) is not None:
        header[i]='UW YEAR'
        print(16)  
        print(header[i])
        j=j+1
    elif  re.search('premium.*',header[i],flags=re.IGNORECASE) is not None : #and re.search('.*ri.*',header[i],flags=re.IGNORECASE) is None
        header[i]='NET PREMIUM'
        print(17)
        print(header[i])
        j=j+1
    print ('run times:'+str(j))
```

This is result of my code, when the iterator iterates to the second element, the if statement runs two times:

```
0
premium
17
NET PREMIUM
run times:1
1
ri pre
12
RI PREMIUM
17
NET PREMIUM
run times:2
2
ri prepaid
11
RI PREPAID
run times:0
```

I dont understand why it runs twice in elif step 12 and 17???
Elif should not check if one condition already meets.
Thank you!!!

Comment: It looks like searches #11 and #16 are missing ```j=j+1```.

Comment: You have an `if` in the middle of the code that should probably be an `elif`.  (For 'BALANCE')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this behavior is you have 2 `if`s in your code.

1. `if re.search('.*policy.*no.*',header[i],flags=re.IGNORECASE) is not None:`
2. `if re.search('.*balance.*',header[i],flags=re.IGNORECASE) is not None:`

So when `ri pre` is iterated, it matches the condition `elif  re.search('.*ri.*pre.*',header[i],flags=re.IGNORECASE) is not None:`
and you update `header[i]='RI PREMIUM'`, so now this `header[i]` also matches the `elif  re.search('premium.*',header[i],flags=re.IGNORECASE) is not None :` from second `if` block as now `header[i]` is `RI PREMIUM`.
Below is the code which I think you require:

```
header=['premium','ri pre','ri prepaid']
import re

for i in range(len(header)):
    j=0
    print(i)
    print(header[i])
    if re.search('.*policy.*no.*',header[i],flags=re.IGNORECASE) is not None:
        header[i]='POLICY NO'
        print(1)
        print(header[i])
        j=j+1
    elif re.search('.*endor.*',header[i],flags=re.IGNORECASE) is not None:
        header[i]='ENDORSEMENT NO'
        print(2)
        print(header[i])
        j=j+1
    elif  re.search('.*customer.*',header[i],flags=re.IGNORECASE) is not None:
        header[i]='CUSTOMER NAME'
        print(3)
        print(header[i])
        j=j+1
    elif  re.search('.*inception.*',header[i],flags=re.IGNORECASE) is not None:
        header[i]='INCEPTION DATE'
        print(4)
        print(header[i])
        j=j+1
    elif  re.search('.*maturity.*',header[i],flags=re.IGNORECASE) is not None:
        header[i]='MATURITY DATE'
        print(5)
        print(header[i])
        j=j+1
    elif  re.search('.*currency.*',header[i],flags=re.IGNORECASE) is not None:
        header[i]='CURRENCY CODE'
        print(6)
        print(header[i])
        j=j+1
    elif  re.search('.*sum.*insured.*',header[i],flags=re.IGNORECASE) is not None:
        header[i]='SUM INSURED'
        print(7)
        print(header[i])
        j=j+1
    elif  re.search('.*ri.*net.*pre.*',header[i],flags=re.IGNORECASE) is not None:
        header[i]='RI NET PREMIUM'
        print(8)
        print(header[i])
        j=j+1
    elif  re.search('.*net.*pre.*',header[i],flags=re.IGNORECASE) is not None:
        header[i]='NET PREMIUM'
        print(9)
        print(header[i])
        j=j+1
    elif  re.search('.*ri.*share.*',header[i],flags=re.IGNORECASE) is not None:
        header[i]='RI SHARE'
        print(10) 
        print(header[i])
        j=j+1
    elif  re.search('.*ri.*pre.*paid.*',header[i],flags=re.IGNORECASE) is not None:
        header[i]='RI PREPAID'
        print(11)  
        print(header[i])
        j=j+1
    elif  re.search('.*ri.*pre.*',header[i],flags=re.IGNORECASE) is not None:
        header[i]='RI PREMIUM'
        print(12)
        print(header[i])
        j=j+1
        
    elif re.search('.*balance.*',header[i],flags=re.IGNORECASE) is not None:
        header[i]='BALANCE'  
        print(13)
        print(header[i])
        j=j+1
    elif  re.search('.*ri.*com.*',header[i],flags=re.IGNORECASE) is not None:
        header[i]='RI COMM'
        print(14)
        print(header[i])
        j=j+1
    elif  re.search('.*ri.*tax.*',header[i],flags=re.IGNORECASE) is not None:
        header[i]='RI TAX'
        print(15)
        print(header[i])
        j=j+1
    elif  re.search('.*uw.*year.*',header[i],flags=re.IGNORECASE) is not None:
        header[i]='UW YEAR'
        print(16)  
        print(header[i])
        j=j+1
    elif  re.search('premium.*',header[i],flags=re.IGNORECASE) is not None : #and re.search('.*ri.*',header[i],flags=re.IGNORECASE) is None
        header[i]='NET PREMIUM'
        print(17)
        print(header[i])
        j=j+1
    print ('run times:'+str(j))
```

Output:

```
0
premium
17
NET PREMIUM
run times:1
1
ri pre
12
RI PREMIUM
run times:1
2
ri prepaid
11
RI PREPAID
run times:1
```